# How to disable Material-UI contrast ratio console errors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My console is full of

`Material-UI: the contrast ratio of 2.590660811372324:1 for #fff on #5EB44B
falls below the WCAG recommended absolute minimum contrast ratio of 3:1.`

error messages which I would like to hide. Is there a way how to do that? I've done the research but could find anything useful.

Here is my `createMuiTheme` code

```
createMuiTheme({
  themeName: 'radovix',
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#5EB44B'
    }
  },
  contrastThreshold: 2
});
```

Note, I'm aware that best approach would be changing the colors that I'm using and therefore solving the error, but that is not possible in my case.

Comment: Generally it's not possible to selectively disable `console.error` for arbitrary dependencies. To do this, Material UI itself would have to surface an option to silence its output.

Comment: Please show your `createMuiTheme` code with the colors that allow reproducing this problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This console error is produced by [getContrastText](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.14/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L145) which is used whenever a `contrastText` color is not [explicitly specified](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.14/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L199).

Instead of specifying `contrastThreshold: 2`, I would recommend explicitly specifying the desired `contrastText` color for those cases where the default `contrastThreshold` of 3 does not pick the one you want. Customization of `contrastThreshold` is really only intended for **increasing** the threshold -- not for decreasing it.

Here's a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { common } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#5EB44B",
      contrastText: common.white
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
        Primary Color Button
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit contrastText]

Comment: That solves my problem. Thank you for the explanation.